# Appending values to existing values of environment variables in go

Tags: shell, go, environment-variables

How can I append another value to an existing value of a **go** environment variable?

If **CGO_CXXFLAGS** has the value **"-I/blah/blah"**

Since the following doesn't work

```
$ go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS="$CGO_CXXFLAGS -I/foo/bar"
```

I want to find a proper way to **CGO_CXXFLAGS** have the value **"-I/blah/blah -I/foo/bar"**

by avoiding to simply re-set all the values plus the new one, such as in:

```
$ go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS="-I/blah/blah -I/foo/bar"
```

Comment: go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS="$CGO_CXXFLAGS -I/foo/bar"

Comment: nope. that doesn't work. if it would be that easy, I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `go env <var_name>` [outputs the effective setting of the variable](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Environment_variables) (i.e. not necessarily the default value), a reliable way to get at the current default value of an environment variable is using [a subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) (assuming a Bash shell):

```
$ (unset <var_name>; go env <var_name>)
```

And then, to set a new value you'd want to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
$ go env -w <var_name>="$(unset <var_name>; go env <var_name>)<value_to_append>"
```

See the following annotated log for a working example:

```sh
# Write an initial default.
$ go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS=-I/blah/blah

$ go env CGO_CXXFLAGS
-I/blah/blah

# Keep in mind that the default can be overridden by a currently set 
# environment variable.
$ export CGO_CXXFLAGS="-I/override/default"

$ go env CGO_CXXFLAGS
-I/override/default

# To print the default value even when it is being overridden,
# in a subshell, unset the environment variable and then run 'go env'. 
$ (unset CGO_CXXFLAGS; go env CGO_CXXFLAGS)
-I/blah/blah

# To set a new default value utilizing the existing default value.
#
# Note: if the default isn't being overridden, no warning will be printed.
$ go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS="$(unset CGO_CXXFLAGS; go env CGO_CXXFLAGS) -I/foo/bar"
warning: go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS=... does not override conflicting OS environment variable

# State after change...
# Default value
$ (unset CGO_CXXFLAGS; go env CGO_CXXFLAGS)
-I/blah/blah -I/foo/bar

# Overridden value
$ go env CGO_CXXFLAGS
-I/override/default
```

Alternatively, you could find the file with the defaults and parse it directly (`go env GOENV` will tell you the file location), but I think it's easier to temporarily unset the environment variable and let `go env` do the work.

---

Equivalent in PowerShell:

```sh
# Write default.
PS > go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS=-I/blah/blah
PS > go env CGO_CXXFLAGS
-I/blah/blah

# Override default.
PS > $Env:CGO_CXXFLAGS = "-I/override/default"
PS > go env CGO_CXXFLAGS
-I/override/default

# Print default.
PS > Start-Job {$Env:CGO_CXXFLAGS=''; go env CGO_CXXFLAGS} | Receive-Job -Wait
-I/blah/blah

# Append to default.
PS > go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS="$(Start-Job {$Env:CGO_CXXFLAGS=''; go env CGO_CXXFLAGS} | Receive-Job -Wait) -I/foo/bar"
warning: go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS=... does not override conflicting OS environment variable

# Final state.
PS > go env CGO_CXXFLAGS
-I/override/default

PS > Start-Job {$Env:CGO_CXXFLAGS=''; go env CGO_CXXFLAGS} | Receive-Job -Wait
-I/blah/blah -I/foo/bar
```

Comment: That works - great job! Since I am working under Windows 10 I needed to use cygwin to try it because neither cmd promt nor Power Shell within Windows can spawn sub shells like you described it. And I am impressed, how much effort one needs to simply achieve such a trivial task like appending a value to an env variable. I will wait a little longer before accepting the answer, maybe someone has an idea on how to do it with a windows shell. However, thank you very much for this excellent answer!

Comment: To be clear, what you're trying to do isn't simply "appending a value to an env variable" (which would simply be `export VAR="${VAR} appended value"` in Bash). What you're actually doing is modifying a file maintained by the `go env` tool. And the above details a solution working within the constraints of the tools functionality.

Comment: Ok, you totally convinced me! Many thanks!